# C++ - Iterate same signature member functions

Tags: class, c++11, iteration, function-pointers, member

I have a class that has a multitude of same-signature functions (creating a data structure that will be ordered by priority). I decided to substitute writing the same signature function call 26 times with a loop, but for some reason it is not working. Does anyone have any idea why the below code throws the below error message? I've been searching a lot, and the results I've found did not bring me closer to a solution. Basically my question is why do I get a bind helper from bind, instead of the proper

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class interface{
/*some interface stuff*/
};

class dataRepresenter
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

class A
{
public:
    const dataRepresenter calculatorOfOneThing(const interface& i);
    const dataRepresenter calculatorOfAnotherThing(const interface& i);

    typedef std::function<const dataRepresenter(const interface&)> calculator;

    std::vector<calculator> myCalculators;

    A();

};

const dataRepresenter A::calculatorOfOneThing(const interface& i)
{
    cout <<"OneThing"<< endl;
}
const dataRepresenter A::calculatorOfAnotherThing(const interface& i)
{
    cout <<"Another"<< endl;
}

A::A()
{
        myCalculators.push_back(std::bind(&A::calculatorOfOneThing, this));
        myCalculators.push_back(std::bind(&A::calculatorOfAnotherThing,this));
}

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    interface i;
    A a;

    for(auto func : a.myCalculators)
        func(i);
    cout << "Success!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
> main.cpp:42:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::function<const dataRepresenter(const interface&)>>::push_back(std::_Bind_helper<false, const dataRepresenter (A::*)(const interface&), A*>::type)’
>    myCalculators.push_back(std::bind(&A::calculatorOfOneThing, this));
> ```

Comment: `std::bind(&A::calculatorOfOneThing, this, std::placeholders::_1)`

Comment: Thank you sir! This solved my problem - at least the compilation part, now I'm runnig out of available memory.